# How to update a parsed xml value

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, dom

I'm parsing an XML as an object and accessing nodes by tagname, I have a problem where the value I'd like to see updated doesn't get updated. The alert shows me the value and it is correct. But i need it to be displayed on the document and which it isn't.

```
var x = xml.responseXML;
var v1 = document.getElementById("sid");
alert(x.getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
v1.innerText = x.getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I also have a question of how can I allow editing/highlight of the node?

Comment: `have a problem where the value I'd like to see updated doesn't get updated. ` what do you mean by that

Comment: @zero298 right i made a mistake, changed to getElementById and still the same problem.

Comment: @srknzl i've made a td element called sid it's currently empty but i need it to at least display the first element. i've made the parsing first and according to what i parsed i need v1(sid) to change

Comment: Does `v1.innerText = "foobar"` work?  Do any updates to any nodes work at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `nodeValue` is `null`, setting its value has no effect (from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue)). However, you can modify the XML content in other ways, for example `.innerHTML`, `.innerText`, `.value` and more. Example with `.innerHTML`:

```js
// creates a Document, as in XMLHttpRequest.responseXML
const docText = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>World</div>
</body>`;
const doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(docText, 'application/xml');

// setting nodeValue over null has no effect...
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].nodeValue);
doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].nodeValue = 'Bye';
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].nodeValue);

// ...but you can modifies the XML in different ways
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML);
doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = 'Bye';
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML);
```